# Do Game Libraries like LWJGL use the original Java2d and Java3d API?

Tags: game-engine, java-2d, java-3d

Ok, so I was planning on learning a little bit about java2d graphics and the java3d API and was wondering if there was any relation between the popular libraries and the raw Java API. I would like to get a good background on wth OpenGL is and try to learn the basics of the Java API before I go exploring into Game libraries and engines.

Thanks for the help in advance,

StoneAgeProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, game libraries don't use Java 2D or Java 3D for performance reasons.

Java 2D/Java 3D are general-purpose abstractions, which means that they sacrifice some performance in order to be easier to use, but for a lot of games performance is really important.

Comment: What do they use then? I mean what programming language.